# Remove '.php' from url redirect

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, .htaccess, apache, redirect-url

I have an URL like:

```
base_url/cloths/mens.php
```

now when we click on this above URL then it should redirect to:

```
base_url/wp/cloths/mens/
```

here we want to remove `.php` extension from URL after redirecting.

**Note**: we are clicking `base_url/cloths/mens.php` from Magento but `base_url/wp/cloths/mens/` is post of WordPress.

We have written like:

```
Redirect 301 /cloths /wp/cloths
```

Here URL is redirecting properly but at the end of URL `.php` is getting append.

We have also tried this but didn't worked:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

How can we remove the `.php` part from the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Found this,

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/cloths/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.com/cloths/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Reference: [Hide .php extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371634/how-to-hide-php-extension-in-htaccess?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Tried suggested solution but not working.

Comment: did you put it on the first line of your .htaccess from root directory of your magento ?

Comment: yes, tried multple suggested solution from stackoverflow also but non of them worked.